# ThrottlingException Rate exceeded SageMaker Studio

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

What I am simply trying to do is shut down my SageMaker studio instance. I am using `datascience--1-0-ml-m5-8xlarge` instance for my SageMaker studio notebook. While running my notebook, I saw that amount of memory being taken was more than the memory available (128 GB). As a result, I reset the notebook. From then on, I am basically not able to shut down the instance as shown in the image[image]

Does anyone know the reason behind this?

Comment: Hi Sumit,

Apologies for the inconvenience.

Could you please create a support case with AWS Support specifying your SageMaker Studio Domain ID and AWS account ID that is running into this issue?

Another option is to create a post in the AWS Forums and there you can DM your account ID to a SageMaker team member.

Thanks,
Amazon SageMaker team

Comment: @Jaipreet I frequently face this problem, is there a solution ?